# How to update unique text in duplicate XML child nodes?

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML block with multiple groups of the same tags/nodes, but the data values are different across these groups. I need to parse them to update the text, but not sure how to do that since each group has the same tags.

I've tried some solutions I found on SE, but they don't get me all the way there.

```
  <attr>
    <attrlabl>STATE_NAME</attrlabl>
    <attrdef>State Name</attrdef>
  </attr>
  <attr>
    <attrlabl>STCOFIPS</attrlabl>
    <attrdef>State/County FIPS ID</attrdef>
  </attr>
```

I want to parse the second 'attr' group to change the 'attrdef' value to "STCOFIPS Value", but not sure how to parse with Python to do that. Expected value:

```
  <attr>
    <attrlabl>STATE_NAME</attrlabl>
    <attrdef>State Name</attrdef>
  </attr>
  <attr>
    <attrlabl>STCOFIPS</attrlabl>
    <attrdef>STCOFIPS Value</attrdef>
  </attr>
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I would recommend using xslt with lxml